# Prove geometrically $\lim_{x\to0} \sin (x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove geometrically $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin (x)=0$

It is easily seen that the statement is true.
but how to prove it geometrically?

Comment: How is it easily seen that the statement is true?

Comment: How do you define $\sin$ function?

Answer (score 2):

For a right triangle with an $x$ and $y$ component, as well as a radius $r$, the $sin(\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$. For a unit circle such that $r=1$, we have the equation $x^2+y^2=1$. We can see geometrically that at $\theta=0$, the starting point of the circle, the radius is still $1$ but the $x$ value is $1$ as well, so $y=0$. Thus $sin(0)=0$.

[image]

For reference.

Comment: What does with $x$ ajd $y$ componet mean?

Comment: They are the side lengths of a triangle, I was user vector terminology.

Comment: Could you provide me a figure?

Comment: Yep, edited. In the picture the side lengths are $a$ and $b$ instead of $y$ and $x$.

Comment: You have proved that $\sin 0=0$ and not that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x=0$.

Comment: Since sine is continuous everywhere $lim_{x\to0}sin(x)=sin(0)$ via direct substitution.

Comment: How do you show that $\sin x$ is continuous?

Comment: The MacLaurin series for sine is uniformally convergent for all $x$ and is thus continuous

Comment: You should have a look at other answers here which show the inequality $\sin x<x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$ geometrically. This inequality is the key to the continuity of $\sin x, \cos x$ and also key to the current question. Using Maclaurin series definition for $\sin x$ is so far removed from the geometrical definition and I don't think OP wants to use Maclaurin series here.

Answer (score 2):

For small $x > 0$, we have $0 < \sin x < x$ (per [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75135)). Now the squeeze theorem is sufficient to show that as $x$ goes to $0$ then $\sin x$ goes to $0$ as well.

Comment: why the downvote? i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the image below:

[image]

Length of **arc** $AB >$ length of **red segment** $AB$ (*straight line joining two points is shortest*)

Now length of **red segment** $AB > $ length of **green segment** $r \sin(x)$ (*hypotenuse is the longest side*)

Thus $rx > r\sin(x)$ or that $x > \sin(x)$

Now apply limit $x \to 0$.

Comment: How does it show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x=0$?

Comment: @blue_eyed What is $\lim_{x\to 0} x$? We have actually graphically showed that $|x| > |\sin(x)|$. So we can talk about limits from both sides. From figure, you can also say that $\sin(x) > 0$ for $x>0$. Now you can apply sandwich theorem.